# YQ 4.7.0 - How to traverse each array elements and update value

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
receivers:
- name: alerts-null
- name: default
  local_configs:
  - api_url: https://abx.com
    channel: '#abx'
    send_resolved: true      
    username: abc-123
- name: devops-alerts
  local_configs:
  - api_url: https://abx.com
    channel: '#abx'
    send_resolved: true      
    username: abc-123
```

The yaml can have multiple "name:" elements in the array and I want to loop all "name" elements and change the value for key "username:" to "xyz-321". Resultant YAML should be as follows:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
receivers:
- name: alerts-null
- name: default
  local_configs:
  - api_url: https://abx.com
    channel: '#abx'
    send_resolved: true      
    username: xyz-321
- name: devops-alerts
  local_configs:
  - api_url: https://abx.com
    channel: '#abx'
    send_resolved: true      
    username: xyz-321
```

I tried to use following yq command, but it did not changed the desired key's value:

```
yq eval '(.receivers[] | select(.name.local_configs.username)) = "xyz-321"' source.yaml > manipulated.yaml
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Why is `internal_config:` empty? Your input isn't even valid YAML. Consider validating it first in http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the indexing to look like this:

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
receivers:
- name: alerts-null
  internal_config:
    username: abc-123
- name: default
  internal_config:
    username: abc-123
```

Then the flowing will work:

yq e '(.receivers[].internal_config.username) |= "new_username"' myFile.yaml